# How to put App in Background&back to Foreground using Selendroid

Tags: selenium, selendroid

How to put App in Background and back to Foreground using Selendroid

Kindly advice me.

Answer (score 0):

http://selendroid.io/advanced.html All the functionality is described here.

Background App Functionality
Selendroid offers you to put the app under test into the background and resume it later.

```
//put the app to the background
driver().backgroundApp();
//resume app
driver().resumeApp();
```

Comment: Extremely sorry for late reply . I am not able to use above function . From which Version they are supported ? \